How do I publish a GitHub repository to NuGet
I have a C# library I want to put on NuGet so others can use it. It’s a public repository and it’ll be a public NuGet library. No restrictions, license key, etc.
It’ll also be very rare that I need to push a new version up as this is code I’ve been using for years. So I don’t need an automated process to do this (although if it’s easy, I’ll take it).
How do I do this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli

@zivkan If you make that an answer, happy to select it.
